# show a drop down list with headings bold in each catergory

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, dropdown

I have many categories which has sub items.Ho to make headings bold.

On server side in C#

```
   string filePath;
        filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Application.xml");
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        ds1.ReadXml(filePath);
        ddlApplication.DataSource = ds1.Tables["CD"];
        ddlApplication.DataTextField = "Application";
        ddlApplication.DataValueField = "Application";
        ddlApplication.DataBind();
        ddlApplication.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", "NA"));
```

Client side

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlApplication" runat="server"  TabIndex="6"
                 class="form-control">
   </asp:DropDownList>
```

I want some heading in it to be bold.how will i do it.I am binding XML

which is as follows:

Application.xml

```
<CATALOG>
 <CD>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Application>'----------Financials---(Only header do not select this entry)</Application>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Application>''DaisyPCD Passenger Business</Application>
  </CD>
</CATALOG>
```